# ID renumbering TOC

Tags: adobe-indesign

I need to create a master table of contents that incorporates
two 100-page documents. Each document has its own table of contents. So, the
master TOC would list both of the TOCs of the two documents as follows:

Introduction
Part One
I.
II.
III. 
IV

Part Two
I.
II.
III.
IV.

Conclusion

The problem I have is that ID doesn’t want to list as per above. Instead, it
lays it out as follows:

Introduction
Part One
I.
II.
III.
IV.

Part Two
V.
VI.
VII.
VIII.

Any thoughts why it is renumbering them?

Comment: Did you renumber your list in Part 2? That is, does Part 2 actually have V, VI, VII or I, II, III?

Answer (score 2):

Try to set these in the Headings paragraph style:

Bullets and Numbering > Numbering style > Mode: Start at

or at second level force restart at this level after any.

For me it works to keep separate heading classes on the same level if that beforementioned approach didn't work out and don't forget to add those styles to the TOC.